# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLabel') - while creating node with relationship with neogma

Tags: neo4j, nestjs, graph-databases

I am working with Nest and Neo4j and I am using neogma as OGM. I've created a function to create Route node in the database and relationship STOPS_AT with Stop node.
There is Stop node in the database with parameter stop_name="Kalemegdan",

Here is the code that throws error

```js
async createRouteWithStop() {
  const route = await this.routeModel.createOne({
    route_id: '2',
    agency_id: '1',
    route_short_name: '2',
    route_long_name: 'Spoljašnji krug',
    route_type: RouteTypes.Bus,
    trip_id: 1,
    route_text_color: 'fff',
    route_desc: 'desc',
    direction_id: 0,
    route_color: 'fff',
    route_url: 'some',
    STOPS_AT: {
      where: [
        {
          params: {
            stop_name: 'Kalemegdan',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    Sequence: 1,
  });

  return route;
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLabel')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getLabel')
at Function.createMany (/usr/src/app/node_modules/neogma/src/ModelOps/ModelOps.ts:992:51)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)   
at Function.createOne (/usr/src/app/node_modules/neogma/src/ModelOps/ModelOps.ts:709:25)
at RouteService.createRouteWithStop (/usr/src/app/src/routes/routes.service.ts:26:19)
at RouteController.createRoute (/usr/src/app/src/routes/routes.controller.ts:16:12)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-execution-context.js:46:28
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:17
```

When I try approach with raw query it sufficiently creates the node ant relationship:

```js
async createRouteWithStop() {
    const stop = await this.stopModel.findOne({
      where: { stop_name: 'Kalemegdan' },
    });

    const route = await this.routeModel.createOne({
      route_id: '2',
      agency_id: '1',
      route_short_name: '2',
      route_long_name: 'Spoljašnji krug',
      route_type: RouteTypes.Bus,
      trip_id: 1,
      route_text_color: 'fff',
      route_desc: 'desc',
      direction_id: 0,
      route_color: 'fff',
      route_url: 'some',
    });

    if (route && stop) {
      const query = `
        MATCH (r:Route {route_id: $routeId}), (s:Stop {stop_name: $stopName})
        MERGE (r)-[:STOPS_AT {Sequence: $sequence}]->(s)
      `;
      await this.neogma.queryRunner.run(query, {
        routeId: route.route_id,
        stopName: stop.stop_name,
        sequence: 1,
      });
    }
```

I can't find out what am I doing wrong in the first example?